# How does _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING affect stdio.h?

Tags: c, windows, preprocessor

`#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING` lets you use `scanf()` without compilation error. However, from what I understand, what you `#define`d in a file cannot be used in other files unless you make it global. How does adding `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING` affect compilation of `stdio.h`?

Comment: It doesn't.  That's why it is defined either on the compilation command line via `/D` or in the precomp-header generator *before* including any standard library includes.

Comment: I start from my `frame.c` file which I copy and rename. It begins with a comments section (purpose, revisons, etc), four `#define`s like the one in question, and then the typical `#include`s that will be needed. It's easier to remove unnecesary lines, than to add them.